# Combining events with Chronicle Queue

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

The chronicle queue doco specifies that it's possible to have Chronicle Sinks on different boxes and the events are distributed to it over the network from a single chronicle queue.  (http://chronicle.software/products/chronicle-queue/)

My question is whether it is possible to do the reverse?

From these chronicle sinks, we would like to generate new events that are then sent to a single new queue. (not update the existing events - as these new events are only generated upon receipt of an appropriate combination of events - otherwise the replicated model would sound appropriate?)
Is it possible to have local queues that are all replicated to a single box in the one queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have local queues that are all replicated to a single box in the one queue?

You can use either a remote connection to have multiple servers write to one queue which is on a central machine (Using Chronicle Engine), or you can have a queue on each server replicated (Using Chronicle Queue Enterprise), and a small process to combine these into a single queue.

Comment: Thanks Peter - sounds like a nice feature to add? :)  The first solution is probably the most elegant providing that all of the failure scenarios are accounted for.